# What's the easiest way to explain What is Hadoop and Map/Reduce?

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

It's very easy to explain NoSQL from high level view - it is basically "key-value" storage. Of course with thousand minor and important things, but in general it's just key value storage.

What's the best way to explain Hadoop and Map/Reduce?
May be some "real world" example which can be easy to give an compare for even newbies?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently found [this great article](http://bartoszmilewski.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/mapreduce-and-the-build-process/) describing Map Reduce :

> I’ve been planning on writing about
>   the Google’s MapReduce algorithm for
>   some time but I couldn’t find a good
>   practical example. Then we had a
>   Northwest C++ Users Group presentation
>   by Steve Yegge and a followup
>   discussion and beers, and I had a
>   little epiphany. Steve was talking
>   about, among other things, the build
>   process. And that’s just a bunch of
>   algorithms that are perfect for
>   explaining MapReduce.

The code examples are in C++, but the content is really language agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great tutorial on map/reduce in general, explaining the background, basics and data flow. I'm finding it useful to explain Google's App Engine implementation as well.

http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html